# Deploy Applet on Apache server

Tags: java, apache, deployment, applet, classnotfoundexception

I've written a Java applet game that I want to deploy on my Apache server. Code + resources are in a self signed .jar with accompanying HTML doc both in the root dir. When I run it on my local machine everything works fine. When I try to run on the server I get a class not found exception. index.html contains

```
<applet code=SpaceRaiderz.class  
 archive=spaceraiderz.jar  
 width=1024 height=768>  
</applet>
```

The class not found is the class named above. Opened up the .jar and its contents are complete. File permissions set to 755. If I click the index.html on my local machine it loads up and runs perfectly. Ftp the same docs to the server and it doesn't work. Anyone had this problem? I found a similar question to this on here but none of the suggested solutions have worked in this case.

Comment: I didn't put it in a package no. I used default package in eclipse. The .jar and the index are both in the same directory yes. the URL is http://www.dweb-x.com/spaceraiderz

Comment: thanks man. I been trying to fix this for over a week. clearly it only dosen't work when I try to view it. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applet (seen [here](http://www.dweb-x.com/spaceraiderz)) works (e.g. showing an asteroids style game featuring a pale green ship that appears suspiciously familiar + sound track) for me in Java 1.7.0_21 on Windows using FF. Refreshing the class cache in the [console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) & then refresh the page might fix the problem for you.

If that fails, there are still more options for testing the applet:

- Usually installing another browser (these things are often due to a problem in the particular browser/JRE combo.).
- There is also the [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/) applet testing environment.  I can highly recommend it, Since I wrote it.
- Go to an internet cafe or the local library to check an applet, if all else fails.